# Is there any way to setup post hooks to a mongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb

I want to sync data from one MongoDB collection(let's call it CollA) to another collection(let's call it collB), was trying to figure out if there was some way to setup post hook in MongoDB that triggers whenever data is updated/inserted in collA.

Here collA has data flowing into it from multiple places. Now I want to sync collA with collB in such a way that whenever there is any change in collA it can be reflected in collB as well.

Here, collB is not an exact copy of collA. Changes in collB are based on changes in collA, they are not exactly the same.

If there are any other ways that can help me with this problem. Please do share.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not have a feature for running code upon changes in the collection in the database server, but you can use change streams to run this code in your application.